# Enable Shared Pager Cache in sqlite using PHP PDO

Tags: php, caching, sqlite

I'm studying sqlite features and I've discovered the [SQLite Shared-Cache Mode](http://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html) which is disabled by default.

Shared-Cache is:

> intended for use in embedded servers

because it shares a single data and schema cache between threads or processes.
I'm interested in using sqlite (with shared-cache) in PHP (and Python) so my questions are:

1) is every PDO connection in a PHP script to an sqlite DB considered a single isolated connection?

2) if yes, using Shared-Cache Mode could improve performance in an high concurrency scenario; to activate Shared-Cache Mode one have to call this C function:

```
int sqlite3_enable_shared_cache(int);
```

how to call that function through PDO?

It seems almost impossible but maybe there is a solution.

Best Regards,
Fabio Buda
Web Developer/Designer @ [netdesign](//www.en.netd.it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've searched through the PHP source code to find an answer for you. No file in `ext/pdo_sqlite/` is ever calling the `sqlite3_enable_shared_cache` function, which means this is not implemented.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following trick to enable SQLite shared cache feature in PHP code:

```
define( 'SQLITE3_OPEN_SHAREDCACHE' , 0x00020000 );
$sqlite = new SQLite3( 'sqlite.db3' , SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE  | SQLITE3_OPEN_CREATE |     SQLITE3_OPEN_SHAREDCACHE );
```

And it works, though somewhat ugly - performance tests on 10k users database shows a little (~3%) performance degradation. Looks like this is not query (results) cache, but a memory cache of raw table data. That's why it should benefit only on really huge databases with high concurrency level.

Comment: This answer is pretty awesome, however the recommended example does not show how to use the defined constant with PDO